# Implementing a dynamic "App under maintenance" screen

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to be able to implement an "App under maintenance" screen/activity dynamically so I can deploy it whenever I need - preventing users from using the app.

I initially wanted to query a `status` document in my Firebase Firestore but didn't want to consume a read every time the app is opened.

My current idea is to create a check in the `onCreate()` method that queries my webpage `www.myapp.com/status` and receives the HTML from that page (either "online" or "offline").

If offline I want to deploy the maintenance activity.

Is this a viable solution and if so is there a better way to implement it? I'm currently in the middle of setting up my Firebase hosting site.

Comment: What firebase can do and your status website cannot, is automatically inform the app when maintenance is complete

Comment: My definition of maintenance is also to protect me from excessive use of third party services such as Mapbox and Firebase - so if requests for those get too excessive I will have to manually implement the maintenance - it can't be automatically detected.

Comment: Depending on the application, it may be best to schedule `ServiceWorker`or something else, to prevent flooding. If your app is expected to be opened several times, during the day, each of those will cost some overhead and network. Also, what happens if the site is down? Are your users free to use? is your system online only?